# Merge multiple responses and dispatch success once only

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngrx

I have the following code which loops through ids and returns response for each ID separately one by one.

```
refresh$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CustomerActions.refresh),
        delay(1000),
        WithLatestFrom(this.facade.customerIds$),
        exhaustMap(([_, customerIds]) =>
          merge(
            ...customerIds.map((id) =>
              this.customersService.getCustomer(id).pipe(
                map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess),
                catchError((err) =>
                  of(CustomerActions.getCustomerFailed(id, err.message)),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

I want to combine the response and get all responses together for customerIds.

I tried moving merge first and then mapping the results, but it resulted in multiple success to be called. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `forkJoin` operator, it behaves like `Promise.all` it will wait until all the inner observables complete and then emit the values.

After the `forkJoin` emits the values you can dispatch the success action.

```js
refresh$ = createEffect(() =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(CustomerActions.refresh),
        delay(1000),
        WithLatestFrom(this.facade.customerIds$),
        exhaustMap(([_, customerIds]) =>
          forkJoin(
            ...customerIds.map((id) =>
              this.customersService.getCustomer(id).pipe(
                catchError((err) =>
                  of(CustomerActions.getCustomerFailed(id, err.message)),
                ),
              ),
            ).pipe(
              map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know where to map the response then? I also tried in this way and always the error is returned.

Comment: @MoannaTabala: 1. Based on the code in your post, the `map` must be inside the `forkJoin` before the `catchError` operator so that it's applied to response from each request. 2. But if you say _"always the error is returned"_ - as in the response from the `catchError` operator, then it has nothing to do with the placement of `map` operator. In this case, you'd need to check if any of the request is throwing an error.

Comment: @MoannaTabala I thought this `map(CustomerActions.getCustomerSuccess)` was dispatching an action. If this transforms the response, I think its best if you can add the map operator in your `getCustomer` method. But if you cant do that, @ruth explains how to map the response.